# Why is a .NET x86 windows service not displayed with *32 in Task Manager?

Tags: .net, windows-services, 32-bit, taskmanager, corflags

I created a dummy windows service using .net 3.5. The service has been compiled for x86 explicitly (32BIT corflag is set).

Process Explorer from SysInternals correctly identifies the process as a 32-bit process. However, task manager does not append the "*32" to the process name.

Why is that?

Cheers,
Alex

Comment: try ask this question at serverfault.com

Comment: This might be too obvious, but is this on a 64bit operating system?

Comment: Yes it is on a 64bit OS, running the 32bit windows service.

Comment: Yep, posted it to serverfault as well.

Comment: Can you provide the links to the cross posts?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you add the following to your service:

Console.WriteLine("{0}", IntPtr.Size);

You'll probably find that because your service is being hosted by the 64-bit service runtime, that your app is forcing itself to run in 64-bits rather than 32-bits.

Comment: There is no console in service.

Comment: But, perhaps he could write it to his log file or the event log?

Comment: Process Explorer from SysInternals correctly identifies the process as a 32-bit process